Probability of choosing 4 cards whose sum is 5 from a deck of 40 cards
Let's say we have a deck of cards excluding face cards, so cards from Ace to 10.
Which of these is the correct way of computing the probability that the sum of 4 randomly chosen cards is equal to 5?
Method #1:
$P(X=5)=\frac{8}{40}\cdot\frac{7}{39}\cdot\frac{6}{38}\cdot\frac{4}{37}$
My logic is that for the first card, there are 8 possibilities. 4 Aces and 4 Two's. For the second card, if the first card was an Ace, there are, 7 possibilities. 3 Aces and 4 Two's. If the second card was an Ace, the third card can be chosen from 2 Aces and 4 Two's. Finally, if the third card was an Ace, the fourth card has to be a Two, so its sample space is just 4 Two's.
Method #2:
$P(X=5) = \frac{8}{40}\cdot\frac{4}{39}\cdot\frac{3}{38}\cdot\frac{2}{37}$
Like Method #1, the first card can be chosen from 4 Aces and 4 Two's. This time however, we will assume that the first card turned out to be a Two. By definition, all the remaining cards have to be Aces.
Method #3:
$P(X=5)=\frac{4}{40}\cdot\frac{4}{39}\cdot\frac{3}{38}\cdot\frac{2}{37}$
We know that in order to have a sum of 5, we specifically need 1 Two card and 3 Ace cards. The first fraction represents the probability of choosing a Two, and the rest pertains to Aces.
I think Method #3 is the most plausible of them all, but I still feel that they're all wrong and that I should just use the hypergeometric formula to find out the probability.

Very often, it is useful to guess some intermediate questions / similar exercices. Q1) What is the probability to get firstly 1 Tow and then for aces. Q2) deduce from previous question the probability to get 1 Two and 4 aces.

As other responses have indicated, the first two choices are wrong.
The third choice, which (like the other two choices) is attempting to use a probability-oriented approach, is also wrong, specifically because it wrongly assumes that the deuce must be the first card chosen.  In fact the deuce can be chosen 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th.
Staying with the probability-oriented approach, and relying purely on intuition to remedy the third choice, you could reason that by considerations of symmetry, the third choice is off by a factor of $~4.~$
The idea is that by considerations of symmetry, if you are given that the first four cards chosen are a deuce and three aces, in some order, the deuce is just as likely to have been the 1st card chosen as the 2nd card chosen, the 3rd card chosen, or the 4th card chosen.
In fact, I will formally demonstrate that the third approach is off by a factor of $~4.~$  That is, I will first show how you would use a probability-oriented approach to the problem, and then I will show how you would use a combinatorics approach to the problem.

$\underline{\text{Probability Oriented Approach}}$
There are $~4~$ mutually exclusive cases to deal with, depending on whether the deuce is the

1st card drawn: 
The probability of this happening is 
$\displaystyle \frac{4}{40} \times \frac{4}{39} \times \frac{3}{38} \times \frac{2}{37}.$

2nd card drawn: 
The probability of this happening is 
$\displaystyle \frac{4}{40} \times \frac{4}{39} \times \frac{3}{38} \times \frac{2}{37}.$

3rd card drawn: 
The probability of this happening is 
$\displaystyle \frac{4}{40} \times \frac{3}{39} \times \frac{4}{38} \times \frac{2}{37}.$

4th card drawn: 
The probability of this happening is 
$\displaystyle \frac{4}{40} \times \frac{3}{39} \times \frac{2}{38} \times \frac{4}{37}.$


So, you have $~4~$ separate terms that must be added together, where each term is equal to
$$\frac{4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 4}{40 \times 39 \times 38 \times 37}.$$
Therefore, the correct answer is
$$\frac{4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 4}{40 \times 39 \times 38 \times 37} \times 4 = \frac{16 \times 4!}{40 \times 39 \times 38 \times 37}.$$

$~\underline{\text{Combinatorics Oriented Approach}}$
Determining the probability combinatorically, you have that the number of different ways of selecting one deuce and three Aces is
$$\displaystyle N = \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} = 16.$$
Then, the number of different ways of selecting any four cards from the deck is
$$\displaystyle D = \binom{40}{4} = \frac{40 \times 39 \times 38 \times 37}{4!}.$$
Therefore, the overall probability is
$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{16 \times 4!}{40 \times 39 \times 38 \times 37}.$$

I disagree because the order in which it is drawn does not matter. It is the number of ways you can draw them, so it does not matter if the deuce is second or third or first. The 4 possibilities for the deuce are counted both in the OP and my combinatorial solution.

@TeodorasPaura In this probability problem, you do in fact have $~4~$ mutually exclusive cases, depending on when the deuce is drawn.  Further, if you examine the Combinatorics section of my answer, you see that I arrived at the same result.  Comparing my Combinatorics computation with yours, you see that you mistakenly omitted the $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}~$ factor, which represents the number of distinct ways of selecting the deuce, from your numerator. ...see next comment

@TeodorasPaura  Assuming that you are right and I am wrong, concerning the probability oriented approach, how do you explain that I got the same computation both ways, in my answer.

@TeodorasPaura To expand on the first part of my rebuttal, you have $~4~$ distinct events, $~E_1, ~E_2, ~E_3,~$ and $~E_4,~$ that could have occurred to satisfy the problem.  Here, the event $~E_k~$ represents that the deuce was the $~k$-th card drawn.  Since these 4 events are mutually exclusive, and since the constraint is satisfied if and only if one of these $~4~$ events occurred, the probability of satisfying the constraint is in fact $$p(E_1) + p(E_2) + p(E_3) + p(E_4).$$

After your first comment I realized that yes indeed you are correct! Thanks! I did not account for suits of the ones which would give an additional factor of four, since they are exclusive. Thanks!!! I will correct my answer accordingly

In the light of the comment from @user2661923 In the first case, you consider 2,2,2,2 it doesn't work. In case 2, also only one particular possibility additionally was considered not all needed as noted by other person 1,1,1,1 is also considered (I didn't specify before). In case 3 your logic is almost correct but you do not consider a factor of 4 for exclusive events and for more combinatorics, I would approach it like this.
First in how many ways can we choose 4 cards out of 40?
$$\binom{40}{4}$$
Now consider four cards you pick out and form an equation as such (can do it in your head but I'll write it down as it is easier to see.)
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5$$
We know that they are all positive and the minimum value is 1 for each. Hence by substitution, we obtain
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 1$$ Now clearly one must be a two but how do we show it in a more general way? We can imagine that we have 3 dividers as such $\text{_| __| ___| ___}$ Whatever is in front of the first one would go to $x_1$ and so on for the rest. So now we can choose to distribute the RHS of the equation. i.e. 1 + 3 dividers and we choose where to put the 3 dividers. (this is for a more sensible understanding) But note that you can choose the suit for 1's as $\binom{4}{3}$ hence
$$\binom{4}{3}^2$$
This gives us the answer in how many ways we can choose the 5 cards so the probability is then:
$$P(X=5)=\frac{\binom{4}{3}^2}{\binom{40}{4}}$$

To get a sum of five, you need exactly one 2 and three aces. The chance for 2AAA is 4/40 times 4/39 times 3/38 times 2/37. Since the 2 can be in any of four positions you multiply by 4.
Now something like “probability that the sum of for random cards is 23” would be seriously difficult. I’d calculate the probability that they are sorted in descending order, ten downto 1, then sorted by face, and the sum is 23, then multiply the result by 24 because they can be in any order.
